# "Updates are not permitted" in Eclipse -bug or feature?

Tags: eclipse

This is the situation: I am the admin of a shared installation of Eclipse, and I want regular users (who do not have write-permission to the installation directory) to be able to update existing plugins. If they try this now they get an error saying something like:

"Your original request has been modified.
[Plugin name] will be ignored because it is already installed, and updates are not permitted.
..."

It works perfectly well for users to install new plugins, just not update existing ones.

Steps to reproduce:

- Install Eclipse (I've tried, among others, Eclipse Classic 3.6.2 and
  3.7, in Linux SUSE Enterprise 10).
- As an admin with write-permission to the installation directory, install a plugin, e.g. EGit 1.0 from
  http://download.eclipse.org/egit/updates-1.0
- As a user (without
  write-permission), try to install a newer version of the plugin (e.g.
  EGit 1.3 from http://download.eclipse.org/egit/updates-1.3).

Perhaps related: If a regular user opens "About Eclipse SDK --> Installation Details --> Installed Software", the "Update" and "Uninstall" buttons are greyed out for every item on the list, though they are not for the admin.

So my questions are: Is this on purpose? and: Can I do something to allow users to update plugins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just have the same error. I removed the plugin of the update configuration file (but it's not the best solution)

> **%eclipse_home%**\configuration\org.eclipse.update\platform.xml

This error is easily reproducible, install a plugin directly into the main configuration directory, and do a manual plugin install, like :

> **%eclipse_home%**\eclipse.exe -configuration **%eclipse_home%**\configuration
>   Install > New software ...

So, the update will not working if you do that.

---

To correctly install a plugin, you just have to drop it into the "dropins" dir, like :

> **%eclipse_home%**\configuration\dropins\**yourplugindir**

Then, the user could use it, or do an update

> (init configuration) **%eclipse_home%**\eclipse.exe -initialize
>   (refresh workspace) **%eclipse_home%**\eclipse.exe -clean
>   **%eclipse_home%**\eclipse.exe
>   Install > New software ...

[The Eclipse runtime options](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fmisc%2Fruntime-options.html)

Best regards,

Comment: The dropins workaround you suggest is what I have been using. I was hoping there might be some other solution but since no-one I've talked to know of one and yours is the only answer here in a month I guess it's time to give up...